# Any callback or broadcast for keyguard unlock using Smart Lock(Face)?

Tags: android, keyguard, google-smartlockpasswords, keyguardlock

Smart lock set using trusted face on device.

after that, when I turn on screen it is secure lock til face recognition finished.

I checked using **KeguardManger.isDeviceLocked**.

it return true when turn on device, and return false after recognition finished.

Is there any callback method or Broadcast to know when face recognition finished?

I checked **DeviceAdminReceiver**, but it doesn't work.

(I expected "**onPasswordSucceeded**" to be called, but it doesn't)

Comment: Hi Miguel, unfortunately google-smartlockpasswords is a different product to the smartlock you're referring to. Please can you remove the tag to aid others looking for smartlock for passwords answers.